# More than one submenu on rails breadcrumbs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navigation, submenu, breadcrumbs

I would like to implement a breadcrumb trail when I visit every page of my rails application, but I can only see until the first submenu. Here's the code in the *navigation.rb* file:

```
SimpleNavigation::Configuration.run do |navigation|
  navigation.renderer = Renderer::Breadcrumbs
  navigation.items do |primary|
    primary.item :home, 'Home', home_path do |secondary|
      secondary.item :courses, 'Courses', courses_path do |tertiary|
        tertiary.item :course, @course.try(:name), url_for(@course), highlights_on: %r(>courses)
      end
      secondary.item :information, 'Information', information_path
    end
  end
end
```

And in the *application.html.erb* file I have:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <%= render_navigation renderer: :breadcrumbs, join_with: ' &gt; ' %>
</div>
```

Where I do wrong? Is it possible to add more than one submenu on the trail?